# Are generic type constraints possible in blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

How can I restrict TModel to be classes only or to be implementing a specific interface?

```
@typeparam TModel
```

cannot get the syntax working.

Comment: It looks like there's an open issue for this in GitHub. There's a solution that might work for you in the thread: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8433#issuecomment-545690917

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution is to put the type constraint *additionally* in a partial code behind class. It works!

Comment: Could you please post an example? I did as you described and Blazor says that the partial has has different base classes, i.e. one (from razor) get compiled without the constraint and the second (c# code behind) with the constraint.

Comment: If Blazor says that the partial has a different base class, then most likely the razor file contains at least one error. That could even be a problem in a used sub view/control

Answer (score 45):

From ASP.NET Core 6.0 onwards, you can use the following syntax to specify generic type constraints:

```razor
@typeparam TModel where TModel : IModel
```

Comment: this is not working for me for some reason. .NET 7, Blazor Server, MudBlazor <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>, <RazorLangVersion>latest</RazorLangVersion>. Anything I could be missing?

Comment: For me it builds but Razor editor throws errors. I also added a code-behind partial class, no help.

Comment: If I keep the constraints in the code-behind, and keep typeparam TModel (without constraints) in the razor, it compiles without errors.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the answer posted by Sven works, but there is one modification I needed to do - add `<RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>` to my *.csproj* file. After that the project was compiled.
So here are my complete files:

1. Project.cs

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion> <!-- Important -->
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>service-worker-assets.js</ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

2. Razor component

```html
@typeparam TViewModel
@inherits PageBase<TViewModel>

<h3>Some text</h3>
```

3. Corebehind

```cs
public abstract partial class AuthenticatedPageBase<TViewModel>
    where TViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
}
```

EDIT:
Well, after deleting the `<RazorLangVersion>` tag from the csproj file it still seems to work.

Comment: RazorLangVersion 3 is implicitely used when using net5.0. I guess it was just a coincidence.