# Can a generic type parameter in a Blazor component be constrained?

Tags: generics, components, blazor

In a Blazor component, you can create a generic parameter for use in a method just as you can in a typical C# class.  To do this, the syntax is:

```
@typeparam T
```

But I would like to know how to constrain it as you can in a C# class.  Something like

```
// pseudocode
@typeparam T : ICloneable
```

For instance, I had the need to create the following component that allows a developer to pass a "Model" of generic type:

**.../GESD.Blazor/Shared/GesdTrForm.razor**

```
@typeparam modelType

<EditForm Model="@Model" 
    OnValidSubmit="@OnValidSubmit"
    style="display:table-row"
>
    @ChildContent
</EditForm>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public modelType Model { get; set; } // here is the use of the generic

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<EditContext> OnValidSubmit { get; set; }

    void demo () {
        var cloned = Model.Clone();
    }

}
```

But at `.Clone()` I get the following error:

> 'modelType' does not contain a definition for 'Clone' ...

Comment: I know this is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60714729/are-generic-type-constraints-possible-in-blazor) question.  However, I believe that question didn't have very much detail, and any thoughts I had on editing it pretty much had me rewriting it completely.  If I'm out of line, of course vote to mark mine as a duplicate of that one, but I think the other question has problems.

Answer (score 18):

For future searchers, I have just found that this feature is [available](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8433) in .NET 6.

Usage looks like:

```
@typeparam T where T : IMyInterface
```

If the generic type cannot be determined by the compiler then it can be specified explicitly:

```
<MyComponent T=MyType>
```

Answer (score 1):

'.../GESD.Blazor/Shared/GesdTrForm.razor' creates a partial class called 'GesdTrForm' under the namespace 'GESD.Blazor.Shared'.  Because it's a partial class, you can create a .cs file, delare the class as partial, and put the constraint in there.

**.../GESD.Blazor/Shared/GesdTrForm.cs**

```
using System;

namespace GESD.Blazor.Shared {

    public partial class GesdTrForm<modelType> where modelType : ICloneable {}

}
```