# How Blazor infer the data type of @typeparam directive?

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

The code below was made using .Net 5.0.203

I've this component

MyComponent.razor

```
@typeparam TItem

<p>MyComponent: @typeName</p>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<TItem> Data { get; set; }

    string typeName;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        typeName = typeof(TItem).Name;
    }
}
```

and here is the page calling the component

Index.razor

```
@page "/"

<MyComponent Data="@items"></MyComponent>

<p>Page: @itemsType</p>

@code
{
    string[] items = new string[2];

    string itemsType;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        itemsType = items.GetType().Name;
    }
}
```

I expected the type of *TItem* in *MyComponent* is *String[]* however it's *String*

How Blazor infer the type of TItem?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the generic constraint of `typeparam TItem` is says when you create the component you must specify what that type is.

When you called your component here:

> `<MyComponent Data="@items"></MyComponent>`

You passed the `@items` object as the parameter.

If you don't *explicitly* tell the component what type it should expect, it will by default use whatever type is passed to it.

You passed it a `string[]` so it said "He gave me a `string[]` so i'm going to assume the `TItem` is of type `string`". It does this because `string[]` is implicitly convertible to `IEnumerable<TItem>` since `TItem` can be any object unless you [constrain that parameter.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) so it can only be certain types

Another thing of note is that `TItem` is the type of the object that is contained within the `IEnumerable<TItem>` parameter. If you want to check to see what type of `IEnumerable` that was passed instead maybe do something like:

```cs
string[] s = new string[] { "fox" };

Check(s);

static void Check<T>(IEnumerable<T> maybeArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(T)); // System.String
    Console.WriteLine(maybeArray is T[]); // true
    Console.WriteLine(maybeArray is List<T>); // false
}
```

If you want `TItem` to be a `string[]` consider instead accepting `TItem` as a parameter instead of `IEnumerable<TItem>`.

Such as:

```cs
[Parameter]
public TItem Data { get; set; }
```

Make sure to include a constraint on `TItem` if you need it to be enumerable.

For more information on how to include a generic constraint in blazor (it's weird) check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60714729/are-generic-type-constraints-possible-in-blazor))